# hibernate criteria issue

Tags: java, database, hibernate, criteria

i have next tables:

```
Table table1
table1Id
field1
field2
field3

Table table2
table2Id
table2_field1
table2_field2
table2_field3
table1Id
```

in this method i get Objects from table1 sorted by some field

```
public List<table1> getMost() {

        DetachedCriteria criteria = (DetachedCriteria) DetachedCriteria.forClass(table1.class);
        //criteria.add(Restrictions.conjunction());
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("field1"));

        List<table1> myList = (List<table1>) findByCriteria(criteria,
                false, 0, 10);//get first 10 elements by some criteria
        return myList;
    }
```

then i need to get Objects from database sorted by some field, but these Objects depend on Objects from table1

```
public Item getTheBest(Long table1Id) {

        DetachedCriteria criteria = (DetachedCriteria) DetachedCriteria
                .forClass(Item.class);

        DetachedCriteria maxQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Item.class);
        maxQuery.add(Restrictions.eq("table1Id", table1Id)).setProjection(
                Projections.max("table2_field1"));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.and(
                Restrictions.eq("table1Id", table1Id),
                Property.forName("table2_field1").eq(maxQuery)));
        List<Item> result = (List<Item>) findByCriteria(criteria, false);

        if (result.iterator().hasNext())
            return result.iterator().next();
        else
            return null;

    }
```

what i want to have is method like this:

```
public Item getTheBest(List<Long> table1Ids)
```

thus this method composes these two above methods and makes less calculations.
the idea of the method is to have a Collection of Objects, sorted by one criteria and after sorting by this criteria, we choose items by some field.
so how can i do it in hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from above is you have 'A Ordered query result and you want to filter it further".

You can do it in native SQL and use hibernate to convert query result to java objects. Following is an example

SELECT 
FROM (SELECT t1.a, t1.b FROM table1 t1 {GROUP BY if needed} ORDER BY t1.a) subTable, 
table2 t2
WHERE t1.a = SOMETHING
AND t2.x = SOMETHING

Comment: @ Insanely Freak. to be more precise, when i selected some data from the first table, i want to select data from the second, where the ids are equal and there can no more than 1 instance of representative with table1id value